# Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having another problem with this exercise: http://lpmj.net/20.php

My problem is that when i go to create a new account, I get the error message:

> Unknown column 'user' in 'where clause'

I've had so many typos at this point that my code is exactly the same as the  code in the book. 
There is only one query in this section that it could be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rcmembers WHERE user='$user'";
```

I'm assuming this means user doesn't exist. how do i create it? isn't it set up at some other point in these lessons?

Comment: No, it means that the table rcmembers doesn't have a column named "user". Can you test your SQL directly in mysql?

Comment: Isn't the table **rnmembers**? Everything else in that chapter starts with **rn**, not rc. (Line 89 of http://lpmj.net/examples.php?c=20&e=5&x=php?)

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: Please paste your code here, not on some other website. http://stackoverflow.com/ is here to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers; what happens when your code host shuts their doors or expires old posts? This would become (more) useless and of no help to others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means `user` does not exist within `rcmembers`. Use something such as PHPMyAdmin to create it.

Comment: i have phpmyadmin pulled up, how do i add this.

Comment: select `rcmembers`. Then, under the `structure` tab, at the bottom you'll see, `add` with `1` selected. Click the `Go` button and fill out the form that follows.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah it looks like you may have skipped a chapter.

Check your db, specifically the rcmembers table for a user column. If it isn't there go back through the tutorials to the point where they told you to create the database